# Lambdifying a function with conditon statements using sympy

Tags: sympy, lambdify

Im trying to lambdify this function

```
def f(x):
    if ceil(x)%2 == 0:
        return -1
    else :
        return +1
a = sympy.lambdify(x,f(x))
```

Im getting an error when i try to do that.
I also tried piecewise , but it is not giving me the desired outcome

```
y = lambdify(x,(Piecewise((1, ceil(x)%2 == 0), (-1,True))))
```

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not easy to translate `if` expressions like that into working `numpy` code.  By itself an `if` does not iterate over the elements of an array, and using an array inside an `if` results in an `ambiguity` ValueError.  Do you really need `lambdify` for this?   Can't you stick with `sympy`, or do the calculation directly in `numpy`?

Comment: hpaulj , yeah , unfortunately I need to pack this code as a function, to be able to apply it to different set of numbers.

Comment: You can write a Python/numpy function that does this without going through `sympy`.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a symbolic expression to `lambdify` so a Python function is no good. Also you need to use symbolic sympy functions and sympy's ceil function is actually called `ceiling`. Finally `==` compares if two expressions are the same which is not the same as constructing a symbolic Boolean. For that you need `Eq`:
That gives

```
In [19]: p = Piecewise((1, Eq(ceiling(x)%2, 0)), (-1,True))

In [20]: p
Out[20]: 
⎧1   for ⌈x⌉ mod 2 = 0
⎨                     
⎩-1      otherwise    

In [21]: y = lambdify(x, p)

In [22]: y([1, 2, 3])
Out[22]: array([-1.,  1., -1.])
```

References:

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#ceiling
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#equals-signs

Comment: `y.__doc__` shows that resulting `numpy` code is `select([equal(mod(ceil(x), 2), 0),True], [1,-1], default=nan)`